# Creating one dataset from several overlapping point datasets using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, point

I am trying to build a model in which I create 9 point data sets that are subsets of one large point data sets. The 9 small point data sets are suitability analyses for tree species. So one point can be suitable for several different species. I'd like merge, join, spatial join these 9 data sets into one data set.  Ideally, the resultant point data set would then have fields (species 1, species 2 species 3, etc.) that represent the tree species suitable for each point location.  I feel like this should be easy to do, but just can't figure out how to do it.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend trying to the process it manually on a small sample and then incorporate those tools/methods in a model.  If you can provide some of the manual steps, then I believe you will get better answers here.

Comment: Do the points coalesce? The problem with point (field) data is that the points wont line up, also the boundary of the species is ethereal, it might be better to identify against some sort of vegetation/ecosystems polygon data. Can you explain more about the point data sets and what's contained in the records of the 7 datasets?

Comment: Are the points identical? If so, and if you have an Advanced level license, you can Intersect the seven layers all at once to get a dataset of points that have two or more species (however any with just one will get dropped, and you'd have to add them back in). If the points aren't identical, or to avoid the one species problem, you might explore iterative use of the Spatial Join tool (ie, join a and b to produce 1, then join c to 1 to make 2, etc.). Could also buffer points, union buffers, then join buffers to a complete set of points (with no duplicates).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've added the model I've built thus far to the original question.  Can you tell me how to get the 9 resultant shapefiles into one dataset where the name of the shapefile (species name) is retained in the attribute table. Many of the points are the same as one point can be suitable for many species. Thank you.

Comment: In looking at the model, I think I would approach it differently. You've already got the points in a single dataset. Rather than split those out to separate files like you have, I'd look at adding nine fields to it, then using Calculate Value on your selections to update those fields.